# can't start zabbix-server on osX: program counter not available for this architecture

Tags: macos, admin, osx-yosemite, zabbix

I've installed `zabbix-2.2 (LTS)` from sources on my `OS X Yosemite`.

When I'm trying to run server by

```
sudo -u _www /usr/local/sbin/zabbix_server -c /usr/local/etc/zabbix_server.conf
```

I'm getting following error in [/tmp/zabbix_server.log](http://pastebin.com/5TM1qUyq).

What can I do?

Comment: The backtrace seems to be the same as in https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-5871. You might wish to reopen that ticket to investigate, but it does not look like the problem is in Zabbix - it crashes in init_snmp() when doing something with SNMPv3. We had similar issues with libcurl - see https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-8770, where it crashed in a cryptograhic library in curl_easy_init(). Does snmpget (maybe with SNMPv3) work for you on the command line?

Comment: I've decided that installing `Zabbix` on `Linux` running on my `Virtualbox` will be simpler and better solution...